# How to test LiveData.asFlow().collect() and reliably verify the method call inside it?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to test a class, which takes a `LiveData` object, converts it to a flow, collects it, and based on the result performs an action.

It works as expected in the main code, but I can't figure out how to test it. It seems that the verification that the code block inside `collect` happens, is never reached, and the test falsely passes.

This is my set up:

```kotlin
class LiveDataClass {

    fun liveData(): LiveData<Boolean> {
        return MutableLiveData(true)
    }

    fun doSomething() {}

    fun decoyMethod() {} // to verify if it's called in the test, just to make it fail
}
```

Class which collects the flow:

```kotlin
class FlowClass(private val liveDataClass: LiveDataClass) {

    suspend fun doSomethingWhenLiveDataIsTrue() {
        liveDataClass.liveData().asFlow().collect {
            if (it) {
                println("Inside the collection")
                liveDataClass.doSomething() // we reach the code here in the test
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the test - I've looked through multiple examples of set up to avoid errors, and even though this test **passes**, and I see the `liveDataClass.doSomething()` **is called**, the verification never happens.

I verify if `liveDataClass.decoyMethod()` is ever called (which it isn't, in fact) and the test is still fine...

```kotlin
class FlowClassTest {

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    private val testScope = TestScope(dispatcher)

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun test() = runTest {
        testScope.launch {

            println("Starting up the test case")
            val liveDataClass: LiveDataClass = mockk {
                every { liveData() } returns MutableLiveData(true)
                every { doSomething() } answers {
                    println("TEST - Doing something")
                }
            }

            val flowClass = FlowClass(liveDataClass)
            flowClass.doSomethingWhenLiveDataIsTrue()

            verify { // never happens and the test passes even though it shouldn't!
                println("Verifying")
                liveDataClass.decoyMethod()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I set up this test so it's actually useful and verifies the calls correctly?

Comment: `doSomethingWhenLiveDataIsTrue()` should never return because it collects an infinite flow. This looks like a design flaw unless you mark it to return `Nothing` to indicate it never returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, both [Hezy Ziv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77204313/7707818)'s and [Tenfour04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203922/how-to-test-livedata-asflow-collect-and-reliably-verify-the-method-call-insi?noredirect=1#comment136104211_77203922)'s answers were helpful - I just had to combine them to get the test to fail on the verification (as it should - `decoyMethod` is never called).

Firstly, indeed `collect` doesn't return anything as it listens to the infinite flow, meaning `doSomethingWhenLiveDataIsTrue()` doesn't return. I had to substitute `collect` for an operator which cancels the flow, such as `first`:

```kotlin
    liveDataClass.liveData().asFlow().first {
        if (it) {
            println("Inside the collection")
            liveDataClass.doSomething()
        }
        it
    }
```

Here the test still passed, but `Verifying` was printed, so there was progress.

Next, I got rid of `testScope.launch` as suggested, and the test finally failed! This meant the test was reliable, so to get it to pass I just need:

```kotlin
    verify { 
        liveDataClass.doSomething()
    }
```

Everything else in the test set up is still necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You're using runTest to run your test as a coroutine. Inside this block, you're launching another coroutine using testScope.launch. This nested coroutine is unnecessary and can be removed.

try the following

```
@Test
fun test() = runTest {
    println("Starting up the test case")
    val liveDataClass: LiveDataClass = mockk {
        every { liveData() } returns MutableLiveData(true)
        every { doSomething() } answers {
            println("TEST - Doing something")
        }
    }

    val flowClass = FlowClass(liveDataClass)
    flowClass.doSomethingWhenLiveDataIsTrue()

    verify { 
        println("Verifying")
        liveDataClass.doSomething() // Verify that this method was called
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails the test with an `UncompletedCoroutinesError`. If I get rid of `runTest` instead, the test method finishes immediately.